# Literal String Search containing Characters

Tags: regex, google-sheets

As part of a countif I'm trying to search for a cell contents that may contain `{}`. It also needs  to be constrained to an exact match within the range. So my first hunch is to go with `regexmatch` but I'm having issues with the `{}` becoming part of the regex. I basically need a way of escaping the entire string from the cell. Here's what I've been trying as an example:

`REGEXMATCH(A2,"(?:^|\s)("&A1&")(?:\s)")`

So say `A1` is `blue{car}` and A2 is `like a blue{car}`, this should match. However I just get a `#REF!` error as its trying to use the `{}`as a quantifier. I know you can escape characters in a predetermined string but as A1 could actually be anything I need a general approach. It seems `\Q…\E` wrapped around `"&A1&"` would be perfect but unfortunately its unsupported in sheets.

Any assistance with this gratefully received!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078) and [RE2 reference](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax), you may easily write a function to escape all special chars that must be treated as literal chars in the regex pattern:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "[.^$*+?()[{\\|]", "\\$0")
```

For `{car}`, it will yield `\{car}` and will only match `{car}`. Note that RE2 regex engine is smart enough to parse the braces in `{car}` as literal braces. The only problem with a non-escaped `{` will appear if the contents between braces is numeric and is located after a non-quantifyable pattern, say, at the start of a string or after an alternation operator.

There is another problem in your regex: you require whitespace or start of string before `{car}` and a whitespace after your `{car}`, but `blue{car}` has no whitespaces at either end and is not at the start of the string. Please reconsider your requirements and amend the pattern accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. This is perfect. The RegEx I posted was a little incomplete as I was umming and ahhing about whitespace in the matches but your solution cures both issues. Very Clever! thanks man.